# Darkening a background image on a bootstrap carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm having trouble formatting my images to be darker in order to read the text on them. I'm using the bootstrap carousel theme and can't get the images darkes! Opacity works but it makes the text more transparent also. As far as I know the `linear-gradient` should be working but nothing is happening. I have tried it on all the classes (not just image class slide).

```css
.slide {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img class="slide"  src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="First slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Welcome to GroupWrites.</h1>
        <p>Where creative writing meets social media. Discover our community of writers and readers and experience social writing. </p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/register" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ?? am i missing something here about bootstrap ? cause, a background on <img> is not seen unless <img> is sized & file not uploaded ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You set the `background` of the `<img>` element but this isn't working because the `background` is only visible in case the image is transparent or missing. You can use `:after` or `:before` to create a new overlay on top of the image with a semi transparent `background` using `rgba`.

You can use the pseudo-class on `.item` or `.carousel-inner` to darken the image  without affecting the text.

```css
.item:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img class="slide" src="http://placehold.it/800x300" alt="first slide">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h1>Welcome to GroupWrites.</h1>
        <p>Where creative writing meets social media. Discover our community of writers and readers and experience social writing.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/register" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting a `background-image` on an `img` will not work because, of course, the background image is in the background! It's covered up by the actual image.

What you need to do is overlay a semi-transparent background on top of your image. You can do this by setting a `background` for the image's parent `div` and ensuring it has a higher `z-index` than the image itself.

```css
.item {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
.item.active {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}
.item .slide {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <img class="slide"  src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="First slide">
</div>
<div class="item active">
  <img class="slide"  src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="First slide">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this to your CSS

```
.carousel-caption{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

Here is the JSfiddle link for the practical implementation. https://jsfiddle.net/ghayyourspyko/tc0ksnex/1/

Another way of doing it is as follow

```
.item{
Position:relative;
}
.item:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

JsFiddle link for the practical implementation of this is below.
https://jsfiddle.net/ghayyourspyko/jscgdLdu/1/

Answer (score 0):

One way to darken a background image on a Bootstrap 5 carousel is by using the "::before" pseudo-element and applying a linear gradient overlay with a transparent black background color (rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)) on top of the image.

You can add the following CSS to the carousel item:

```
  .item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try filter `brightness` to adjust image darkness:

```css
body{
  font-family:calibri;
}

div {
  width:200px;
  padding:20px;
  color:#fff;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}

div img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:180px;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:8px;
  filter:brightness(40%); /* You can try with filter to give darkness to each image */
}
```

```html
<div>
 <img src="//picsum.photos/250" />
 <h2>Heading</h2>
 <p>This is my first paragraph</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: There's no need to put greetings and niceties on this platform, as they tend to (quite rightly) get removed by editors. The aim of Stack Overflow is to create something that looks like documentation (for millions of future readers).